# Best way of transforming XSLT in J2EE webapp

Tags: java, performance, xslt

I have a web application which has several pages, of few are using XSLT stylesheet for rendering webpages. Problem here is that for every request I have to get the XSLt file from file system and then run transformation which is no good for performance. What can be the best solution here in memory tranformation, Is that a good solution ? or some other solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Templates are compiled XSLT scripts.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTemplates(javax.xml.transform.Source)

Answer (score 0):

the framwork I know for transformations xml, xslt, html, is [apache cocoon](http://cocoon.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same stylesheet repeatedly you definitely want to compile it once and save the result in memory. The JAXP interface represents a compiled stylesheet as the Templates object; cache this somewhere.